# summary of the last response on a tab

Tags: feature-request

It is good if the responses tab has information about the last response: in a form like *n min ago* or several initial characters of the last response. Then, you will know when a new response arrives witout opening the responses page. I am imagining something like iphone's badge on an email icon telling you how many unread messages there are.

In addition, it will be useful if the responses tab also appears among the 'top bar' (where Questions, Tags, Users, Badges, Unanswered are)

Comment: 'Responses' as in comments users have left to an answer/comment by yourself? As in the `@sawa` type? The universal inbox covers that already, doesn't it?

Comment: Is it the one Harry is mentioning below? Then, I didn't know that. I will use that. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In addition, it will be useful if the
> responses tab also appears among the
> 'top bar' (where Questions, Tags,
> Users, Badges, Unanswered are)

You already have a similar functionality on top-left corner as shown in following image:

[image]

and when you click on it all your latest responses are displayed under inbox:

[image]

It also contains several initial characters of the last response as you requested.

---

***Edit:-*** As shown in following image it displays the number of unread messages, which doesn't require hovering on it:

[image]

---

As @Jeff commented: It displays time when you hover on particular response.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that. But, what I meant was that I wanted something of a push flavor, not pull. You have to hover that position once in a while to get the information, and it is not as convenient as something showing up as a push-type information. Although, it is good to know what showed me, and I will use it; better than not having it.

Comment: the time is shown in a tooltip if you hover your mouse

Comment: @sawa: you will have number-round on that indicating number of unread-messages. Look at my eidt.

Comment: @Jeff: yes you are right them time is shown. sorry I don't know that. correcting my anwser.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize that before.