# Activity drop-down: how to see what is new

Tags: feature-request, recent-activity

*I understand that the new drop-down isn't finished yet.*

However, I'm missing now the info what has changed since my last check. Today I noticed that my reputation count had a new value, but I couldn't say by what value it changed, not even if it was higher or lower than on Friday. So I clicked on the new arrow and the column for today and week had all zeroes. So that didn't help. I then clicked on the reputation tab and saw the reason for the change as somebody had upvoted a question of mine on Saturday.

I read a bit here on meta and found a thread that mentioned that a week starts on Sunday and it has to do with timezones and cultural aspects or whatever (mind that a week starts on Monday here). Is that why "week" shows 0?

Long story short, I'm really missing that update info. The envelope was really convenient as it showed what had changed since the last time I had clicked it. To speak for myself I can't yet see how that drop-down is better compared to the envelope, actually I think that you removed quite some functionality.

Would it be possible to extend the new drop-down to hold that update-info please?

Answer (score 1):

If you see now you will find something similar to following image:

[image]

This shows recent reputations changes which is what you might want.This also shows recent badges earned. Even though counts are wrong which I have asked [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82616/wrong-favorite-count-in-drop-down).

Comment: Then you are lucky because I didn't see the red squared info. Do you know what "recent" means?

Comment: @sjngm: it shows recently changed reputation. Not same as the envelop icon that if you click again on it recent items will still remain in it which is not the case in envelop.

Comment: somebody decided to upvote this question and I can now officially confirm that the only thing I see in what you marked as red square is "+10 Activity drop-down: how to see what is new" as a link. **Nothing** else.

Comment: @sjngm: Sorry for late reply. I had a problem described [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83400/how-to-login-to-so-if-https-is-blocked). Yes you are right it just shows current reputation change. if you are looking for latest response then see [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82975/summary-of-the-last-response-on-a-tab/82987#82987)

Answer (score 1):

The "since last checked" information is not part of the dropdown, but instead is now a part of your user profile page, on the tabs at the top.

[image: Image of tabs with some showing recent changes]

Unlike the old envelope report, these will update *individually* as you visit each specific tab. With the above example, I could visit responses and get that `5` cleared without affecting the report on reputation.

In the case of reputation and responses, the corresponding tab will also *highlight and expand* all of the entries that correspond to this "last seen" data.

[image: You can tell from this that I don't check my responses all that often. And yes, I accidentally cutoff the top of the tab in the screenshot.]

There's no "landing" page like the old envelope used to have. However, clicking on your reputation number will bring you straight to the reputation readout. There is currently no equivalent for responses, although your Global Inbox handles most of that.

All of this hinges on accessing those tabs, of course. If you suffice to get most of your reputation updates via the most recent reputation changes at the bottom of the display name dropdown, then those tabs can go for days or weeks without being "seen". Use it frequently, though, and it can become an effective tool for tracking the exacts of your changes.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. All the changes on the profile page make sense now. I felt a bit left alone when the envelope was gone, but now I think that the previous functionality is back again. So what do we need the arrow for now? ;)