# how to login to SO if https is blocked?

Tags: discussion, login

My company has blocked https so how to login to Stack Overflow if https is blocked? is it even possible?

Comment: *All* HTTPS? Or can you ask some sysadmin to exclude well known OpenID providers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One option, login from unblocked computer somewhere else and bring the cookie to company.

Comment: How do you do that? For other reasons I spent quite a while trying to work out how to extract a specific cookie from Firefox, it doesn't seem very easy...

Comment: @Benjol, I have installed firebug, and firecookie :-) there is quite easy option to view/edit/create cookies in firecookie.

Comment: @SMark, ok, good to know. I can't mark your comment as accepted, but it is :)

Comment: @Benjol, actually, better option is if you can tunnel https to http, but I can't get to work somehow, probably my lack knowledges on ssl.

Comment: I guess that if tunnelling would go undetected, then there would be no reason to block HTTPS to start with?

Comment: @You: Thnx man. Your option works. Now I'm logged in by bringing cookie from other pc to mine. But now I can not accept your until Moderator merge this account to mine. I don't how to notify moderator about it.

Comment: @Harry Joy, probably flag one of your post, and inform moderators and ask for merge accounts?

Comment: @You: okay. I'll try.

Comment: @You: Moderator have merged my accounts and now accepting your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to find an OpenID that lets you login without https.

Comment: and let moderator merge accounts to new one, may be :-)

Comment: @S.Mark: you can add a second openid to your account (and then delete your first one, making the second your primary one). So you can change it yourself; you don't have to create a new account

Answer (score 0):

If you can set up your own server:

- Host something [like phpMyOpenID](http://bendodson.com/projects/phpmyopenid/) yourself.
- If you insist on using a third party OpenID service that requires HTTPS, have a look at [DeleGate](http://www.delegate.org/delegate/HowToDG.html#sslgateway) as a gateway for HTTP clients to a HTTPS server. See also [Log into Gmail without SSL](https://superuser.com/questions/43571/log-into-gmail-without-ssl/43725#43725) on Super User. (Not for the faint of heart. And again, you'll need to run it on some public server: it won't work when running within your work's network.)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and found out that using Google as openID will allow me to log in.
The problem is, my associated OpenID is myOpenID, so what I did was:

1. Log in through cell phone.
2. click 'add openID' on profile page
3. Login with Google.
4. Ha-ha

Comment: Just to be sure: does Google allow non-HTTPS logins?

Comment: Mhm.. just checked and I am not sure. It could be that the company allows Google https...