# Activity arrow next to username: Can it indicate new changes for favorites and revisions?

Tags: feature-request

This question is similar to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/83079/148842) question, but I'm not concerned about reputation that much.
Another similar question can be found [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/83286/148842).

I've noticed that since we moved to arrow, I've stopped noticing information about favorited questions. Back in the old times, envelope would change color when there's some new information. It used to change color for any new information and we had to go and see the page there and so on and so on.

Now with the arrow, we can instantly see reputation information in detail. On the other hand, very little info is given to revisions and favorites.

So here's my problem: There is a separate space for reputation on the top bar and each time we notice its change, we can hover over the down arrow and see details on the reputation change and that is good.

However, there's no clear indicator when a favorited question had an update or when there were revisions. You have to go to the arrow and see numbers there and then decide if something changed and after that click on favorites or revisions and see the list of changes. To me this looks like a step back compared to the envelope.

I believe that we need a way to be notified when there are changes to favorited questions or when there are revisions. Could the arrow for example change color when there are new revisions or favorite changes?

Another idea that occurred to me is to make the reputation details area changeable. For example have it display the reputation details by default. When user hovers mouse over favorites or revisions, it would change to show details of favorites or revisions. Hovering mouse over reputation would bring back the reputation display.